# Angular 5 (mousenter) not working

Tags: angular

i updated my full project to angular 5, two weeks ago and i've notice the event (mouseenter) (mouseleave) are not working anymore on a component of mine.
This was perfectly working before. 
Is this deprecated or something or do i miss an import ??

(click) works... the html template of the comp

```
<i *ngFor="let step of steps"
    #ratingPicker
    [ngClass]="{
        'fa-star': !step.half && step.selected,
        'fa-star-o': !step.half && !step.selected,
        'fa-star-half-o': step.half,
        'pre-selected': step.pre_selected,
        'selected': step.selected,
        'fa-lg': (size == 1),
        'fa-2x': (size == 2),
        'fa-3x': (size == 3)
        }"
    (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter(step, $event)"
    (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave(step, $event)"
    (mousemove)="onMouseMove(step, $event, ratingPicker.getBoundingClientRect().width)"
    (click)="setRating(step.index)"
    class="feedbacks-element fa" aria-hidden="true">
```

the component

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rating-picker',
  templateUrl: './rating-picker.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rating-picker.css']
})
export class RatingPickerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
```

Comment: show code please .

Comment: oh just tryed on chrome this works... it seems there is a bug with safari ... chrome works greate but safari just not fires any of mouseenter mouseleave .... dunno why

Comment: angular 5 seems to have quite a few bugs in safari requiring polyfills or workarounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be rooted in a compatibility problem with Safari. Solution comes from this answer: [Default Angular-CLI Project Fails in Safari - culprit strict mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147752/default-angular-cli-project-fails-in-safari-culprit-strict-mode/47311565#47311565)

```
npm install webpack-dev-server@2.7.1 --dev
cp -R ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server ./node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/
ng serve
```

Comment: wow great, was waiting for an update from angular but didn't find anything on this on their bug tracker.
Thank you man