# Ng-cli serve not working in IE but ng-cli build does, whats missing?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-cli

So I'm hosting the app and I noticed, if I use a IE11 to browse the app, `ng serve` will fail while `ng build && yarn http-server` will be successful. I suspect this is due to polyfill but I'm not certain of the right way to tackle it. What am I missing?

If its not straight forward way to accomplish I would preferably want a method to run ng-serve in a build config fashion.

Comment: care to give a reason for closing?

Comment: which version of angular version are you using? Besides, can you post the related code in the angular.json or tsconfig.es5.json file and the package.json file? you could also check them whether them configure the right setting to start the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a know problem. A lot of info all around the place, so I'll try to summarize it here:

It all seems like it is a webpack issue that affects: IE, and Safari

1. There is [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8596) open issue. It will eventually lead you back to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147752/default-angular-cli-project-fails-in-safari-culprit-strict-mode/47311565#47311565). It 
   basically says that changing webpack (downgrading) seems to fix the issue.

> The error is due to the development server's live reload client code
>   (from webpack-dev-server) which requires basic ES2015 support.

2. I've also seen that `--no-live-reload` might work, but this is totally incovenient.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone through that ticket, it looks like its just tignored.

Comment: for whoever found this thread `--no-live-reload` didn't work for me.